# Magento 2 Configurable Product REST API add to cart?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, rest-api

Hi I am trying to add configurable product add to cart using REST API in magento 2.1.8. but its getting

> {
>       "message": "You need to choose options for your item." }

**Note:-** For logged in users i am trying to add.

```
{
   "cartItem": {
      "quote_id": "308",
      "sku": "WSH12",
      "qty": "1",
      "product_option": {
         "extension_attributes": {
           configurable_item_options [
               {
                  "option_id": "", 
                  "option_value": ""
               }, {
                  "option_id": "", 
                  "option_value": ""
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Screen shots:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Please clarify how to consider **option_id** an **option_value**?
   what exact values need to consider as per this example?
2. Is it default magento 2 api issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: yes i have followed below post

Comment: I also tried it, but no success, but difference is I am not trying with json format, I am using array format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do a GET (rest/V1/products/YOURSKU) on the required item, you can see what the option_value / option_id are.

For an example product on my store -

```
"configurable_product_options": [
        {
            "id": 84,
            "attribute_id": "186",
            "label": "Subscription Term",
            "position": 0,
            "values": [
                {
                    "value_index": 137
                },
                {
                    "value_index": 133
                },
                {
                    "value_index": 134
                },
                {
                    "value_index": 135
                },
                {
                    "value_index": 136
                }
            ],
```

With this, the POST would be -

```
{
 "cart_item": {
 "quote_id": 193,
 "product_type" : "configurable",
 "sku": "YOURSKU",
 "qty": 1,
 "product_option": {
     "extension_attributes": {
       "configurable_item_options" : [
           {
              "option_id": "186", 
              "option_value": 137
           }
     ]
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @thanks BigDaddyl i will check and get back to you thanks for the quick response